# Why aren’t there any “ultra high energy density” batteries on the consumer market?

Tags: lithium-ion

I have heard of ultra high energy density lithium cells that boast incredible figures from [oxis](https://oxisenergy.com/), [sion](https://sionpower.com/products/), and [solid energy](http://www.solidenergysystems.com/hermes/) that blow current li-ion cells out of the water. There are probably even more comapnies out there that I don’t know. But when I try to do digging on them, all I get are generic news articles about the product. And the official websites for these companies say nothing about price. (No listed price = very expensive) I’m surprised that they haven’t creeped out into the consumer market *at all*. I would suspect that old cells would be down cycled and resold onto the consumer market like many commercial battery packs/modules. I am also surprised that these are not sold to consumers even at a steep premium.

Why are these supposedly ground-breaking cells so seemingly nonexistent and mysterious?

Comment: Perhaps things like high temperature and dangerous chemicals are factors.

Comment: Most of these companies use a lot of future tense "will do" "will be able to provide" and so on. Most of them are not able to mass produce to meet the values they are advertising yet. They are all a year or two from getting out into the world, and then a year or to to get out into the consumer market.

Comment: I wish I had a dollar for every announcement about a new wonder battery I have read. The bottom line is that none of these batteries yet exist as commercial products. Some may exist some day, but some of the companies are designed to separate investors from their money.

Comment: Next year my aim is to release dilithium crystals as a product and blow all those new battery tech start ups out of the water.

Comment: If we used all the vapor from those vaporware products in 18th century steam engines, world's energy problems would be solved by now.

Comment: I’ll smoke to that idea.

Answer (score 2):

When I carefully look at the three manufacturers (oxis, sion, solid energy) that you mention, I notice some commonalities:

- in development
- production testing
- building a factory
- etc

So my conclusion is that they're not producing and selling these batteries yet. Even if they would have a (in their view) finished product, it will take some time (think at least a year) before any well-known manufacturer (Samsung, Apple etc) will use their batteries. This is because manufacturers want to do their own tests on the batteries to be absolutely sure that they are good enough to use and safe to use in their products.

Think about the Samsung Note 7 battery issue, no manufacturer wants to repeat that as it harms customer confidence.

So sure, some new battery technologies will come but it just takes time.

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of technologies in development that could boost energy density to 3x current Li battery levels, or more. Some have got as far as producing laboratory examples that will survive several hundred cycles. The problem is that typically getting something out of the lab and into large scale production takes between 5 to 10 years. Just because some PhDs can hand build one by no means guarantees that they can be machine made in the millions by semi-skilled labour.

Comment: It seemed to me like they are in small scale production

Comment: @Ryan That may be so. Small devices in low quantities with high failure rates in production and highly qualified staff troubleshooting all the time. In principle these new technologies should be no more expansive than existing mass production batteries